# pandas strip partial text from column based on list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that contains the titles of the bout and a list of the weight classes. I need to search the Fight_Name column to against the Weight_Class list and populate a column in my df like below:

Edit to clarify: I need the output like this. I only have a list of weight classes and i need to make it a column in my df that matches based on the Fight_Name column

| Fight_Name | Weight_Class |
| --- | --- |
| Middleweight Bout | Middleweight |
| UFC Interim Middleweight Title Bout | Middleweight |
| UFC Light Heavyweight Title Bout | Light Heavyweight |
| Strikeforce Atomweight Title Bout | Atomweight |

Comment: Okay. Let us know what went wrong.

Comment: What is the actual question? Is the shown DataFrame the input or the desired output?

Comment: desired output sorry. I dont know how to pull the weightclass out like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

`Note` - Replace `weight_class_list` in the for loop with your list name -

```
def extract(x):
    for item in weight_class_list:
        if item in x:
            return item
        
df['Weight_Class'] = df['Fight_Name'].apply(lambda x: extract(x))
```